# Parameter count mismatch. Threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to create a server/multi-client chat program. The client side program works perfectly. The problem is at the server's one. When I am clicking the Connect button the client should connect to the server but

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.
```

comes up and the server program crashes. I am pretty sure that this happens because I want the server side program to save the client's ip and nick name into 2 ListBoxes.
My events:

```
        private void server_OnClientConnected(object Sender, ConnectedArguments R)
    {
        server.BroadCast(R.Name + " has connected."); //That message is shown at client's chat box. 
                                                      //So there is no problem with the connection.

        UpdateListbox(un_list, R.Name, false); //Here is the problem. It works when I comment out them, 
                                               //without updating the list boxes of course
        UpdateListbox(ip_list, R.Ip, false);
    }
```

when the client is connected.

```
        private void server_OnClientDisconnected(object Sender, DisconnectedArguments R)
    {
        server.BroadCast(R.Name + " has disconnected.");

        UpdateListbox(un_list,R.Name,true);
        UpdateListbox(ip_list, R.Ip, true);

    }
```

when the clients is disconnected.

My method:

```
    public delegate void UpdateList(ListBox box,object value,bool Remove);


    private void UpdateListbox(ListBox box, object value, bool Remove)
    {
        if (box.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            if (value != null && Remove==false)
                box.Items.Add(value);
            else if (value != null && Remove==true)
                box.Items.Remove(value);

        }
        else
        {
            box.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateList(UpdateListbox), value);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance, George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to pass the `bool Remove` parameter. Change your line to this:

```
box.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateList(UpdateListbox), new object[]{box, value, Remove});
```

Or if you want to avoid making the same mistake in the future, you can use lambdas with [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416.aspx):

```
box.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => UpdateListBox(box, value, Remove));
```

Had you forgotten the `Remove` argument there, you would have received a compile-time error.

Comment: Well the first one didn't really help. Same problem came up when I tried to connect. I don't really know how to use lambda expressions but I tried to copy and paste 

`box.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => UpdateListBox(box, value, Remove));`

instead of 

`box.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateList(UpdateListbox), value, Remove);`

but it didn't work also because I cannot convert labda expression to type "System.Delegate" because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Also, I just fixed a mistake in my "first one" code. (sorry, I misread the method signature) so try that again.

Comment: Okay I fixed it, I used your suggestion but I added box object to object array. So it worked as 

`box.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateList(UpdateListbox), new object[] { box, value, Remove });`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that, again! Really serves me right for not actually writing out the equivalent code myself in Visual Studio or LINQPad. Glad to hear you got it working!